# how to stop a thread when the response time exceeds within stipulated time - JMETER?

Tags: jmeter

I have a test that needs to stop a thread after waiting 10 secs to get the response . I have tried Flow Control Action sampler , but it doesn't help . Please suggest me something to get this done .

Answer (score 0):

1. On [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) level set "Action to be taken after a Sampler error" to `Stop Thread`

   [image]
2. At the "Advanced" tab of the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler (or better, [HTTP Request Defaults](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/why-its-so-important-use-jmeters-http-request-defaults) configuration element - this way the setting will be applied to all HTTP Request samplers) define "Response Timeout" as `10000` milliseconds:

   [image]